# como hacer que no se repitan numeros en mi matriz

Tags: java

estoy haciendo una matriz, pero la cosa es que necesito que los numeros por columna no se repitan, me podrian ayudar? adjunto mi codigo y esta captura.

```
 System.out.println("\nIngresa numero de jugadores (2-20)");
  ref.jug=sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Numeros de jugadores");
  int pos[]=new int[ref.jug];
  
   int og[][]=new int[ref.jug][6];
  for(int i=0; i<ref.jug; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
    og[i][j]=rd.nextInt(20-1)+1;
                              }
      }
          for(int i=0; i<ref.jug; i++){
             for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
    { 
        System.out.print(og[i][j]+" ");
          }
    System.out.println("");
                          }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]